# mwl calender moment.js - Day names in german

Tags: angularjs, internationalization, momentjs

I use the mwl calender and it works fine. My only problem is to view the day names in german. In my AngularJS calendar- controller I have configured moment like this:

momentJS is included in the html using:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/bower_components/moment/min/moment.min.js"></scr‌​ipt>
```

then used as below:

```
function CalendarController(..., moment, ...) {
    moment.locale('de', {
      week : {
        dow : 1 // sets start day to monday
      }
    });
```

so I set the locale to de but the day names are still in english (Monday, Thusday, ...)
Does anyone have a hint what I have to do in order to view day names in german?

Comment: did you try with only `moment.locale('de');` to check first if the days are translated or no ? the `week : { dow : 1 }` is already set for 'de' you don't need it.

Comment: no, this does not work, neither week starts at monday nor day names are in german. With dow : 1 the week starts at monday - this works fine.

Comment: your problem is that your momentJS doesn't recognize the locale 'de' nor any locale.. Make sure you import/include the locale too, are you by any chance using systemJS to import moment ?

Comment: I only included moment with: **<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/bower_components/moment/min/moment.min.js"></script>**. Are there moment- locale files I have to include?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should import the locale too, use this instead:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/bower_components/moment/min/moment-with-locales.min.js"></scr‌​ipt>
```